# asp:Repeater problemas con el switch(Checkbox) en <label for="id_input"></label>

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy ocupando el siguiente [ejemplo](https://codepen.io/andrewteece/pen/aCidp) para poder maquillar mis checkbox.

El problema surge cuando intento ocupar el Repeater:

```html
<!-- Default switch -->
<asp:Repeater ID="id_repeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <input  id="ID_INPUT" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox" runat="server" />
                <label for="ID_INPUT"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("va_nom_fun") %>'></asp:Label>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

```
<input name="id_permiso$ctl00$ID_INPUT" type="checkbox" id="rpt_permiso_ctl00_ID_INPUT" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round">
```

y por lo tanto el `<label for="ID_INPUT"></label>`   Queda inutilizable y es necesario para que pueda hacer el efecto CSS de Switch..

Intenté poner `id='<%# Eval("va_cod_igo") %>'`   pero al parecer no se puede hacer eso

Por otro lado, también intenté

```
label for="<%=ID_INPUT.ClientId%>"></label>
```

y por razones que desconozco me lanza un error y no puedo hacer uso de

```
id="ID_INPUT"
```

al parecer dentro del repeater queda inutilizable por que me salta un error aun del lado del servidor no lo puedo llamar para por ejemplo no puedo hacer el:

```
if(ID_INPUT.Cheked!=false)
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes controlar el `ID` que `asp.net` genera cuando un control esta dentro de otro componente, si quisiras mayor control en el html deberias ir pensando pasarte a `asp.net mvc`.

Aunque creo que en este caso podrias usar el evento `ItemDataBound`, el cual se produce por cada item que se crea en el repeater al asignarle el datasource

[Using Repeater ItemDataBound event in ASP.Net example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Repeater-ItemDataBound-event-in-ASPNet-example.aspx)

Con este evento podrias acceder al contorl usando `FindControl()` y asignar la propiedad, pero esto solo funciona con controles que sean de asp.net, por lo que deberas agregarle el `runat=server`

```
<label for="ID_INPUT" runat="server"></label>

protected void OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {

        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;

        var label1 = (item.FindControl("ID_INPUT") as ??);

    }
}
```

Pero el problema que veo no veo que exista un `Html Control` para el label

[HtmlControls Namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Quizas debas usar un `<asp:Label >` y asignar la propiedad `AssociatedControlID`